# How does TensorReduce use assumptions?

Tags: linear-algebra, assumptions, tensors

I would like to use `TensorReduce` by assuming that certain patterns of functions are tensors. From documentation of `TensorReduce`:

> If `TensorDimensions[ten]` does not return a list of dimensions, then
>   the expression ten is returned unchanged.

I would have inferred from above that if I modify `TensorDimensions[ten]`, `TensorReduce` should work. Thus I did

```
Unprotect[TensorDimensions];
TensorDimensions[f_[g__]] := d & /@ {g};
Protect[TensorDimensions];

Assuming[ t ∈ Arrays[{d, d}, Antisymmetric[All]] ,
 TensorReduce @ TensorContract[ t\[TensorProduct]f[DN, DN], {1, 4}]]
```

However, this doesn't work. i.e. `TensorReduce` does nothing, and the result is

```
TensorContract[ t\[TensorProduct]f[DN, DN], {{1, 4}}]
```

To compare, having defined

```
Assuming[ t ∈ Arrays[{d, d}, Antisymmetric[All]] && 
          f[DN, DN] ∈ Arrays[{d, d}],
 TensorReduce @ TensorContract[ t\[TensorProduct]f[DN, DN], {1, 4}]]
```

> ```
> - TensorContract[ t\[TensorProduct]f[DN, DN], {{2, 4}}]
> ```

the result is indeed simplified as desired:

I'd like to understand what are the assumptions that `TensorReduce` really uses. Is there a way that I can work with `TensorReduce` as above, with pattern like declaration of tensors?

PS: Currently I generate a list of assumptions of `f_[g__]` using `Cases`, and put those assumptions together in `Assuming`. This makes the code slow and ugly.

Comment: This question is answered perfactly by Jose at https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=zh-cn#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/9hp2AMCU_ZU